# fileparse error while exec cgi script- perl cgi

Tags: perl, cgi

I use the below code to handle upload file through perl cgi. I try fileparse but gives path error. What am I doing wrong here?

exec fail through below error.

```
fileparse(): need a valid pathname at ./testupload.cgi line 15
```

Any inputs?

Source:

```
 use strict use CGI;
 use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );
 use File::Basename;
 $CGI::POST_MAX = 1024 * 5000;
 my $safe_filename_characters = "a-zA-Z0-9_.-";
 my $upload_dir = "/home/test/Desktop/uploads";
 my $query = new CGI;
 my $filename = $query->param("textfile");
 my ($name, $path, $extension) = fileparse($filename, '\..*');
 $filename = $name.$extension; $filename =~ tr/ /_/;
 $filename =~ s/[^$safe_filename_characters]//g; 
 if ($filename =~ /^([$safe_filename_characters]+)$/)
 { $filename = $1; }
 else
 { die "Filename contains invalid characters"; }
```

Comment: Presumably you are getting the path wrong. Possibly making wrong assumptions about the current working directory. Possibly not having permission to access the right directory.

Comment: My Code :
use strict
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );
use File::Basename;
$CGI::POST_MAX = 1024 * 5000;
my $safe_filename_characters = "a-zA-Z0-9_.-"; my $upload_dir = "/home/test/Desktop/uploads";
my $query = new CGI;
my $filename = $query->param("textfile");
my ($name, $path, $extension) = fileparse($filename, '\..*');
$filename = $name.$extension; $filename =~ tr/ /_/;
$filename =~ s/[^$safe_filename_characters]//g;

Comment: if ($filename =~ /^([$safe_filename_characters]+)$/){
           $filename = $1;
   }else{
         die "Filename contains invalid characters";
    }

Comment: Edit the code into your question. Don't dump it as an unreadable mess in comments.

Comment: CGI.pm is ancient and horrible. It should generally be avoided. It isn't going to be in the new release of core Perl 5.

Comment: Sory for that I tried to post it in my question but window does not allow me because in correct format

Comment: There is a big "code" button in the UI. Try it.

Comment: Have you tested what value `$filename` actually contains?

Comment: $filename contains upload file name. I am uploading text file.

Comment: What is horrible about CGI.pm?  I've always liked it a lot.

Comment: I tried code button but still not able to format it as per stackoverflow requirement.

Comment: @reinierpost Look at the section at the very start of the documentation which reads 'CGI.pm HAS BEEN REMOVED FROM THE PERL CORE'

Comment: @TechPerl Stop what you're doing and read the StackOverflow site documentation.

Comment: Where is that and what is that?

Comment: @TechPerl — How do you know that `$filename` contains the filename? Have you logged it out so you can check?

Comment: @Dr. Avalanche: Thanks. The pointer there is useful, but I haven't found a comprehensive summary. This post is useful: http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2013/05/msg202460.html

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source for File::Basename](https://metacpan.org/source/SHAY/perl-5.20.1/lib/File/Basename.pm), it seems that you'll only [get that error message](https://metacpan.org/source/SHAY/perl-5.20.1/lib/File/Basename.pm#L107) if you pass an undefined value as the first argument to `fileparse()`. So it definitely looks like `$filename` is undefined. Which means that your line:

```
my $filename = $query->param("textfile");
```

Isn't doing what you think it is. Perhaps you're not passing a value for that CGI parameter. Perhaps you've got the name of the form input wrong. But without seeing how you are calling your program, it's impossible to be any more help.

A few more comments on your code:

- `use strict use CGI;` - presumably this gives a syntax error
- Please use `CGI->new` in place of `new CGI`
- The second (and subsequent) arguments to `fileparse()` should be file extensions. `\..*` doesn't look much like a file extension to me
- You remove all of the unsafe filename characters from `$filename` and then check to see if there are any unsafe filename characters in `$filename`. Is that really what you intended?

And then there's the standard advice that learning CGI in 2014 is a lot like learning to use a typewriter. It'll work, of course, but people are going to think you're a bit old-fashioned and strange :-)